# 'char' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable' error in C#

Tags: c#, char

I've just started learning C# and am attempting to create a new line with the "char" variable. I am getting the error "'char' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'" on line 42.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Program1
{
    class Program
    {
        // This is where your program starts
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Prompt user to enter name
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your name, please:");

            //Read the name entered
            string name = Console.ReadLine();

            //Greet the user with name and request the hour
            Console.WriteLine("Hello " + name + ", enter the current hour:");

            //Read the hour entered
            string hour = Console.ReadLine();

            //Ask the minute
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the current minute:");

            //Read the minute entered
            string minute = Console.ReadLine();

            //Subtract hour by 3 to get NY hour
            int NYhour;
            int NYh = Convert.ToInt32(hour);

            NYhour = NYh - 3;

            //Verify current time and prompt New York time
            Console.WriteLine("If it is " + hour + ":" + minute + " then it must be " + NYhour + ":" + minute + " in New York.");

            //Line break
            Char ('n');  //<--- error here

            //Ask the current temperature in fahrenheit
            Console.WriteLine("What is the current temperature in fahrenheit?");

            //Read the current fahrenheit temperature
            string fahrenheit = Console.ReadLine();

            //Ask the NY temperature in fahrenheit.
            Console.WriteLine("What is the fahrenheit temperature in New York?");

            //Read the NY fahrenheit temperature
            string NYfahrenheit = Console.ReadLine();

            //Subtract current temperature from NY for difference
            int tempDIF;
            int fahrenheitCUR = Convert.ToInt32(fahrenheit);
            int fahrenheitNY = Convert.ToInt32(NYfahrenheit);

            tempDIF = fahrenheitCUR - fahrenheitNY;

            double tempDIFC = (tempDIF - 32) * (5.0 / 9.0);
            tempDIFC = ((double)((int)(tempDIFC * 100.0))) / 100.0;

            //Prompt with fahrenheit temperature currently and in NY then convert to celsius
            Console.WriteLine("If it is " + fahrenheit + "° fahrenheit now and " + NYfahrenheit + "° fahrenheit in New York then there is a " + tempDIF + "° fahrenheit difference or a " + tempDIFC + "° celcius difference!");

            //Wait for user to acknowledge the results
            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to terminate...");
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

The code is also here: http://pastebin.com/EERPcFAs

Comment: Just replace it with `Console.WriteLine();`

Comment: I think you should continue studying. You need to learn how to declare and initialize a variable of a specific type and how to use them. The line char('n') from your code really makes no sense. First, 'n' is not used for line break. Second, char is a type, like int or string or any other. It is not a function that will do anything in the console.

Answer (score 3):

You should use this to line break:

```
Console.WriteLine()
```

In C# parentheses using for method calls.So to do this:

```
Char('n')
```

You must have a `Char` method but you don't. Char is a value type,and can not be using like this as the error said.

Comment: Isn't `Environment.NewLine` a better option?

Comment: @AlexandreRondeau isn't `Console.WriteLine()` a better option instead of writing two newlines.

Comment: I meant using Environment.NewLine instead of the "\n"

Comment: `Console.WriteLine("\n");` **!=** `Console.WriteLine();`

Comment: @L.B you right my bad, fixed.just I'm confused when I see Char('n') `\n' came to my mind :D

Answer (score 1):

Saying `Char ('n');` is like saying `42;`  It isn't actually viable code.  You might be trying to say `Char aChar = ('n');` and then you have the variable `aChar` to use when you need it.